# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm missing something extremely basic on this. - I've tried to implement react-router. I'm getting an error on page load:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'children' supplied to 'Router'.
    in Router
```

Also, the configured routes don't seem to be being picked up correctly
e.g. `Warning: [react-router] Location "/policies" did not match any routes`
I've had a look around SO but nothing seems to be relevant to what I have.

What am I doing wrong?

**index.js**

```
import 'core-js/fn/object/assign';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import {Dashboard} from './components/Main';
import {OverviewComponent} from './components/dashboard/OverviewComponent';
import {PoliciesComponent} from './components/dashboard/PoliciesComponent';
import {ReportingComponent} from './components/dashboard/ReportingComponent';

// Render the main component into the dom
//ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Dashboard}>
        <Route path="/policies" component={PoliciesComponent} />
        <Route path="/reports" component={ReportingComponent} />
    </Route>
  </Router>),
 document.getElementById('app'));
```

**excerpt from Main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import {OverviewComponent} from './dashboard/OverviewComponent';
import {PoliciesComponent} from './dashboard/PoliciesComponent';
import {ReportingComponent} from './dashboard/ReportingComponent';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="mainContainer" className="container-fluid">
        <div id="menuSidebar" className="col-md-2">
          <MenuItems />
        </div>
        <div className="topNav"></div>
        <div className="mainPanel">{this.props.children}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: I'm having this exact issue, I have two routes one for authenticated and one for non-authenticated users, and the non-authenticated is working perfectly and they look almost identical to me.  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Any solutions really?